# Google debug: How to debug a library in executable jar - Error : File was not found in the executable

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

Details: Java app on GKE : Kubernetes

I am able to debug all the java files of my executable jar but not the inner jars/libraries. My executable jar's main code is in implementaion jars/libraries, I have source code of those libraries. How can I debug them?

I have used `gcr.io/google-appengine/openjdk` and added following entry points:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"  ,"-Dcom.google.cdbg.module=watchlist", "-Dcom.google.cdbg.version=develop","-jar","/watchlist.jar"]
```

I think I need a way to put all the class files of required library jars in my main executable jar's web-inf/classes folder. How can I do that?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using an IDE.

In my experience, when you got the implementation from your java file to the class file (CTRL + click normally does the trick for classes or Right click and go to implementation for implementation), you reach the class file of the jar.

There you can go to the top of the class file and click on the package. This will open the jar from target of your project explorer. 
You will be able to find your desired class there, or in a different package.

I hope this approach works for you.

PS: I use Intellij

Comment: I am using stackdriver debug of GCP and i have uploaded my source code there. Any idea about that?

Comment: I think I need a way to put all the class files of required library jars in my main executable jar's web-inf/classes folder. How can I do that?

Comment: I believe the only way to get this to work was if the code of the libraries you want to debug were actually packaged with your own source code. In other words, I don't think it's feasible.